# Render JSX element in react-contenteditable

Tags: reactjs, jsx, contenteditable

In `react-contenteditable`, the `html` attributes only accepts `string`, how can I manage to add JSX element with `eventlistener` with in the string.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-wilbur-lqo5d?file=/src/App.js)

```
import ContentEditable from "react-contenteditable";
import "./styles.css";

const text = "I want to order cheese chicken pizza.";

const Elems = {
  cheese: (
    <span style={{ color: "red" }} onClick={() => alert("clicked cheese span")}>
      cheese
    </span>
  ),
  chicken: (
    <span
      style={{ color: "red" }}
      onClick={() => alert("clicked chicken span")}
    >
      chicken
    </span>
  )
};

export default function App() {
  const swapText = () => {
    const text_array = text.split(" ");
    console.log(text_array);
    const a = text_array.map((item) => {
      if (item in Elems) item = Elems[item];
      else item += " ";
      return item;
    });
    return a;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>React contenteditable</h2>
      <ContentEditable html={swapText()} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert react elements to markup using [`ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(element)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup). This would help with the styles, but not with the click handler:

```
if (item in Elems) item = renderToStaticMarkup(Elems[item]);
```

For the items to be clickable, you'll need to pass an `onClick` handler to `<ContentEditable>` component (or a parent of it):

```
<ContentEditable onClick={handleClick} html={swapText()} />
```

You would also need to identify the clickable elements. In this example, I've `data-action` tags to both of them:

```
const Elems = {
  cheese: (
    <span style={{ color: 'red' }} data-action="cheese">
      cheese
    </span>
  ),
  chicken: (
    <span style={{ color: 'red' }} data-action="chicken">
      chicken
    </span>
  )
};
```

The click handler searches the event target or a parent that has the `data-action` tag using [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), if it finds one it acts on the tags value:

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
  const target = e.target.closest('[data-action]');

  if (!target) return;

  const action = target.dataset.action;

  alert(action);
};
```

Working example - [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-contentediable-click-item-8z0bz?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Excellent, it works, after looking at you solution, I got another idea, I can use jquery, to check on `mousedown` event if the `target` has the `attr` `data-action`.
Anyways thank you much got solution in 2 ways .

Comment: You're welcome. jQuery's event delegation works similarly to what I did here.

Comment: In `renderToStaticMarkup` can we make the span element draggable? 
[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-wildflower-frluk)

Comment: No, but you can add an event handler to `ContentEditable` that will facilitate dragging elements under it.